# Updating phpMyAdmin

Tags: centos, yum, phpmyadmin

I'm running CENTOS 5.7 I have phpMyAdmin - 2.11.11.3 installed via yum.
Trying to update to 3.5.6.

If I run:

```
yum list installed | grep phpMyAdmin
```

I get:

```
phpMyAdmin.noarch                      2.11.11.3-2.el5                 installed
```

However, if I run:

```
yum update phpMyAdmin
```

I get:

```
No Packages marked for Update
```

How should I go about fixing this? Should I completely uninstall phpMyAdmin & reinstall from source? I'm a bit of a noob at this, but it seems like I should just be able to update phpMyAdmin via yum? Is there some dependency thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is called `phpmyadmin3` for version 3.5 (on the `epel` repo). Read the doc to check about the recommended update procedure.